# Service Stack Json Response Contains Extra Characters

Tags: json, web-services, servicestack

I'm converting a Web Api project to service stack and in json responses I'm getting an extra line of text before and after the json content. I'm using fiddler to capture the response.

Edited for brevity, here is an example:

```
18d
[{"id":  ...  }]
0
```

What are these lines? I can't find any configuration option that would seem to correspond to keep this from happening.

## Edit

I went back and started with the basic hello service stack example, and here's what I got for a response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/1.0
X-Powered-By: ServiceStack/3.943 Win32NT/.NET
Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 15:48:49 GMT

1b
{"Result":"Hello, JRandom"}
0
```

I'm assuming the extra response lines are the result of the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header.

Comment: interesting what OS/platform is this on (e.g. Win/ASP.NET)? and do you have a stand-alone example that we can run to repro?

Comment: self-hosting on windows, and it looks like a similar question was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15928202/servicestack-self-hosted-service-uses-chunked-encoding-is-unbuffered

Comment: ok yeah then it's just using chunked-encoding and not an error, we don't specify to use chunked by default, HttpListener decides this on its own.